# Encrypt file with AES in python and Decrypt in C++ Windows

Tags: c++, windows, encryption

I wrote this code to encrypt a file in python with AES and now I send this file over HTTP to a client in C++ using Windows OS. And I want to decrypt this file on the C++ client, but I haven't found any libraries/usefull code to help me with this manner.
Here is the code for python:

```
def derive_key_and_iv(password, salt, key_length, iv_length):
    d = d_i = b''
    while len(d) < key_length + iv_length:
        d_i = md5(d_i + str.encode(password) + salt).digest()
        d += d_i

    return d[:key_length], d[key_length:key_length + iv_length]

def encrypt(in_file, out_file, password, key_length=32):
    bs = AES.block_size # 16 bytes
    salt = urandom(bs)
    key, iv = derive_key_and_iv(password, salt, key_length, bs)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    out_file.write(salt)
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        chunk = in_file.read(1024 * bs)
        if len(chunk) == 0 or len(chunk) % bs != 0: #final block
            padding_length = (bs - len(chunk) % bs) or bs
            chunk += str.encode(padding_length * chr(padding_length))
            finished = True
        out_file.write(cipher.encrypt(chunk))

password = 'ABCDE' # some password

with open("some_file.bin", "rb") as in_file, open("enc_some_file.enc", "wb") as out_file:
    encrypt(in_file, out_file, password)
```

Update:
I am updating this question regarding my try with WinCrypt. I am trying to compile from VS CODE using MSYS64 g++ compiler on Windows. Here is the code that I am trying to run. I also have some additional libraries to help me with the client-server part, such as libcurlpp and libcurl.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define AES_KEY_SIZE 32
#define IN_CHUNK_SIZE (AES_KEY_SIZE * 10) // a buffer must be a multiple of the key size
#define OUT_CHUNK_SIZE (IN_CHUNK_SIZE * 2) // an output buffer (for encryption) must be twice as big

using namespace std;

string host = ""; #some host

int main(void)
{
    curlpp::Easy req;
    req.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Url(host));
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("enc_calc.enc", ios::out | ios::binary);
    myfile << req;
    myfile.close();
    getch();
    wchar_t *in_file = (wchar_t *)"enc_calc.enc";
    wchar_t *out_file = (wchar_t *)"calc.dll";

    wchar_t default_key[] = L"ABCDE";
    wchar_t *key_str = default_key;
    const size_t len = lstrlenW(key_str);
    const size_t key_size = len * sizeof(key_str[0]);
    const wchar_t *filename1 = (const wchar_t *)"enc_calc.enc";
    const wchar_t *filename2 = (const wchar_t *)"calc.dll";

    HANDLE hInpFile = CreateFileW(filename1, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);
    if (hInpFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Cannot open input file!\n");
        system("pause");
        return (-1);
    }
    HANDLE hOutFile = CreateFileW(filename2, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hOutFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Cannot open output file!\n");
        system("pause");
        return (-1);
    }

    DWORD dwStatus = 0;
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;
    wchar_t info[] = L"Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider";
    HCRYPTPROV hProv;

    if (!CryptAcquireContextW(&hProv, NULL, info, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %x\n", dwStatus);
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        system("pause");
        return dwStatus;
    }
    HCRYPTHASH hHash;
    if (!CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_SHA_256, 0, 0, &hHash)) {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptCreateHash failed: %x\n", dwStatus);
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        system("pause");
        return dwStatus;
    }

    if (!CryptHashData(hHash, (BYTE*)key_str, key_size, 0)) {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptHashData Failed : %#x\n", err);
        system("pause");
        return (-1);
    }
    printf("[+] CryptHashData Success\n");

    HCRYPTKEY hKey;
    if (!CryptDeriveKey(hProv, CALG_AES_128, hHash, 0, &hKey)) {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptDeriveKey failed: %x\n", dwStatus);
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        system("pause");
        return dwStatus;
    }
    printf("[+] CryptDeriveKey Success\n");

    const size_t chunk_size = IN_CHUNK_SIZE;
    BYTE *chunk = new BYTE[chunk_size];
    DWORD out_len = 0;

    BOOL isFinal = FALSE;
    DWORD readTotalSize = 0;

    DWORD inputSize = GetFileSize(hInpFile, NULL);

    while (bResult = ReadFile(hInpFile, chunk, IN_CHUNK_SIZE, &out_len, NULL)) {
        if (0 == out_len) {
            break;
        }
        readTotalSize += out_len;
        if (readTotalSize >= inputSize) {
            isFinal = TRUE;
            printf("Final chunk set, len: %d = %x\n", out_len, out_len);
        }

        if (!CryptDecrypt(hKey, NULL, isFinal, 0, chunk, &out_len)) {
            printf("[-] CryptDecrypt failed: %x\n", GetLastError());
            break;
        }
    
        DWORD written = 0;
        if (!WriteFile(hOutFile, chunk, out_len, &written, NULL)) {
            printf("writing failed!\n");
            break;
        }
        memset(chunk, 0, chunk_size);
    }

    delete[]chunk; chunk = NULL;

    CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
    CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
    CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);

    CloseHandle(hInpFile);
    CloseHandle(hOutFile);
    printf("Finished. Processed %#x bytes.\n", readTotalSize);
    return 0;
}
```

The errors I'm getting are regarding the windows.h library, such as:

"ULONG does not name a type" and other types in windows. and at runtime: "Cannot Open input file", not sure why, even tho the file is downloaded in the current folder and I'm trying to open it as such in the code.

Comment: Are you asking for a recommendation of a C++ library?

Comment: @SitiSchu Yes. I have to mention that, I have already tried Wincrypt and It doesn't work. I would like to compile the library for windows C++ with MinGW64 g++.

Comment: Why don't you post the WinCrypt code and try to fix it and what exactly is the problem (*It doesn't work* doesn't say much)?

Comment: @Topaco Ok, I will update my question.

Comment: And also remove the python tag, (and the window tag since its not GUI related) as this will be a C++ question then

Comment: The C++ code seems to be missing the determination of the salt, the derivation of key and IV using MD5, and the setting of the IV. Also, your errors don't even seem to be related to encryption. Maybe you should split the problem into file I/O, getting the salt, key/IV derivation and encryption to narrow down the issues.